# Activity Monitor paused

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms, troubleshooting, activity-monitor

Some of our end-users still like to use the Activity Monitor in SQL Server.
When setting up our SQL-server 2016 servers the activity monitor always ends up in a paused state when the users are not part of the "Administrators" group in Windows (on the server).

When the users are part of the Administrator-group all data gets through (so probably not a Firewall-problem).
We also tried:

- Adding the users to the "Performance Monitor Users" and "Distributed COM Users"
- In COM: Changing the limits of "My Computer" and the permissions on "Windows Management and Instrumentation".
- The users also have the "View server state" permission in SQL Server.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Kind Regards,

Tim

Comment: I've never seen a satisfying answer to this outside of granting sa access. I'd use this as an opportunity to move those users off using that, because [Activity Monitor is bad](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/why-i-dont-use-sql-server-activity-monitor/) and if they are smart enough to understand its results, they should be using a better alternative (like sp_whoisactive or sp_blitz mentioned in the link).

Comment: Probably because cpu usage is fetched using WMI , and requires OS privileges. I'd report this as bug to Ms and see if they can handle lack of OS privileges more gracefully.

Comment: @LowlyDBA: We already use the sp_blitz sollution but some of our developpers tend to like the visual graphs in the Activity Monitor. But i might be a good idea  to set up a report in PowerBi to make sp_blitz more graphical for the end-users. Thanks.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi: Thank you for the tip, found the sollution for this with your tip. I'll post it below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution for this after @TiborKaraszi 's tip about WMI.

- Run wmimgmt.msc on the DB-server
- Open the properties of WMI-Control (right-click)
- Open the security tab.
- Select CIMv2 and click the Security button below
- Add or locate the account or group
- In the permissions list, check Remote enable.